# DB onUpgrade SQLiteException from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite

I've implemented a logic to upgrade my database to new versions. And everything works fine, otherwise I would get thousands of crashes.
Any way there are about 100 crashes per month during onUpgrade and all of them from BroadcastReceiver `BOOT_COMPLETED`.
Here is a crash log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (SQLiteConnection.java)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:903)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:514)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init> (SQLiteStatement.java:31)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql (SQLiteDatabase.java:1770)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL (SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.common.helpers.DbUpgradeHelper.upgradeToTrngSounds (DbUpgradeHelper.java:213)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.common.helpers.DbOpenHelper.onUpgrade (DbOpenHelper.java:101)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:398)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.common.helpers.DbOpenHelper.getAllMeta (DbOpenHelper.java:224)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.model.proxies.ControlProxy.queryMetadata (ControlProxy.java:101)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.presenter.Presenter.bindData (Presenter.java:179)
  at com.abdula.pranabreath.presenter.receivers.ReminderBootCompletedReceiver$1.run (ReminderBootCompletedReceiver.java:27)
```

So this `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver loads all reminders from a database and schedules next alarm trigger time.
Here is the receiver class:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        final PendingResult result = goAsync();
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                switch (action) {
                    case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                        sPresenter.bindData();
                        ReminderDelegate.setNextReminder();
                        break;
                 }
                result.finish();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

sPresenter.bindData(); call loads all data from a database using getAllMeta method and than it calls getWritableDatabase() from the inside. After onUpgrade is called.
In this scenario seems like a user have upgraded the app and haven't opened it but rebooted the device.
onUpgrade method:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        int version = oldVersion;
        db.beginTransaction();

        switch (version) {
            case LAUNCH_VERSION:
                DbUpgradeHelper.upgradeToAccurateExp(db);
                version = ACCURATE_EXP_VERSION;

            case ACCURATE_EXP_VERSION:
                DbUpgradeHelper.upgradeToGuruRelease(db);
                version = GURU_RELEASE_VERSION;

            case GURU_RELEASE_VERSION:
                DbUpgradeHelper.upgradeToMeditation(db);
                version = MEDITATION_VERSION;

            case MEDITATION_VERSION:
                DbUpgradeHelper.upgradeToTrngSounds(db);
                version = TRNG_SOUNDS_VERSION;
        } 
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
   }
```

And the last method where a crash actually occurs:

```
static void upgradeToTrngSounds(final SQLiteDatabase db) {       
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE trainings ADD COLUMN public_id INTEGER"); // CRASH HERE
        db.execSQL("UPDATE trainings SET public_id = user_owner");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE trainings ADD COLUMN dur_mode INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
}
```

There is no other complainings - only SQLiteException.
Could you please help me to find out, if it is a problem with onUpgrade not performing on UI-thread? Or is there something wrong with BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the logic into an IntentService? Broadcast Receivers shouldn't handle long operations, it should work only as a dispatcher.

Comment: How could I move it? To set next reminder seems a short enough operation for broadcast receiver itself. I have spied this snippet from google's alarm project.
But what I can do if database wasn't upgraded during launch but instead during BOOT_COMPLETE.